# Echo out the PHP Function Or Return?

Tags: php, function

I am not good with functions and classes in PHP. I am echoing a function instead of return because it gives me desired results. But it also echo out the result value to my desired page. This function is in class. Just see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrB8g.png) and you will understand what i want.

Echo out the total numbers:

```
<?php 

echo $results->get_total_marks_subjects($subject_detail['subject_id']); 

?>
```

Here is function code in class:

```
    while($rec  =   mysql_fetch_array($link)) {
        //i think the code below echoes out that message.
        echo    $rec['total_marks']." | "; 
        //return    $rec['total_marks'];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question ? i don;t see any function here !

Comment: I didn't post the all function code, because the problem is that i am echoing value in function instead returning. Just see the image and then you will what i want.

Comment: just comment echo, and you'll get what you want

Comment: Are you asking if its better to echo or return the result from inside a function ? My preferred way is to return data from a function, then deside if i will echo it or use it as a php variable/state at the time i call it.

Comment: Echo gives me all values in a result set but if i return then it gives me only first value. Let say, if there are 3 test in database then return i s giving me only one, while echo gives me all and that all i want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going guess what you want...

I'm assuming it's going to echo $rec['total_marks'] multiple times as it is going through results of a mysql object.

instead of:

```
<?php echo $results->get_total_marks_subjects($subject_detail['subject_id']); ?>
```

try:

```
<?php 
     $_results=$results->get_total_marks_subjects($subject_detail['subject_id']);
     foreach ( $_results as $_result ) {
         echo $_result;
     }
?>
```

insteadof:

```
     while($rec  =   mysql_fetch_array($link)) {
        echo    $rec['total_marks']." | "; i think, this code echo    out that message.
        //return    $rec['total_marks'];
        }
```

try:

```
     $_tempcounter=0;
     while($rec  =   mysql_fetch_array($link)) {
        $arrayofresults[$_tempcounter++] = $rec['total_marks'];
        }
     return $arrayofresults;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer...but sadly, it's not working...It is making my page blank...there is may be a problem in your code.

Comment: i could not find a solution by using php but hide those values by using CSS. For the time being, it is working. Thanks for your replies.